# references in node.js callbacks

Tags: node.js, reference, callback

I have just been writing some tests when a fundamental problem emerged. I wrote the bare skeleton of a test framework. It first collects all tests (their callbacks) in an array and executes them afterwards in a separate loop. However, this

```
//test.js
var testArray = [
    {
    n : 1,
    d : 'text1'
    },
    {
    n : 2,
    d : 'text2'
    }
];

var cbs = [];
function fnWithCallback(d, cb) {
    console.log('d=('+d+')');
    cbs.push(cb);
}

for(var i=0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
    var v = testArray[i];

    fnWithCallback(v.d, function() {
    console.log('v=('+v.n+'), i=('+i+')');
    });
}

for(var j=0; j < cbs.length; j++) {
    cbs[j]();
}
```

When I run this sample I get this:

```
> node test.js
d=(text1)
d=(text2)
v=(2), i=(2)
v=(2), i=(2)
```

That means in the callback 'v' has been assigned to the last element of the last array and 'i' to it's last state, not to the one when the callback has been 'created' and passed to the 'fnWithCallback' function. However, since 'd' is printed out within the callback it hast the value of the element when 'fnWithCallback' has been called.

"Unlooping" the loop does not help.

```
var v = testArray[0];

fnWithCallback(v.d, function() {
    console.log('v=('+v.n+')');
});

v = testArray[1];

fnWithCallback(v.d, function() {
    console.log('v=('+v.n+')');
});
```

results in the same behaviour.

Can someone explain this and provide a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a closure

```
fnWithCallback(v.d, (function(v,i){
    return function() {
        console.log('v=('+v.n+'), i=('+i+')');
    };
})(v,i)));
```

Comment: works perfectly fine, thanks! for other readers: there is a missing ')' - it should be })(v,i))); in the last line

Comment: can u just give a short explanation (or links to reading) too? are the values passed by-value to the closure, why does it work with the closure and not without it?

Comment: @forste, have a look at this: http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/ also you could google "javascript closures" for more information.